# .Net web service, performance for number of services vs size of service

Tags: .net, web-services

I work on a large .Net Winforms project with a Web Service connection to Sql Server.  It has evolved to have around 10 different services grouped by business function.  Some of these services have gotten quite large with many functions.  What is the best practices on this?  Is there a performance hit to having hundreds of functions in the same service?   Would it be better to have more smaller services?  It seems fairly easy to use as it is, the services are fairly isolated from each other, and you usually know right away which service you want.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to have fewer calls to the web service methods that return larger data sets than having multiple calls to web methods returning only small amounts of data. The rule of thumb is to avoid as much as you can to traverse process and network boundaries.

Comment: I have the same number of calls and the same amount of data.  My question is would it be better to have 1000 calls in 1 service or 100 calls in 10 different services or 50 calls in 20 services or does it matter at all?

Comment: I disagree. Only retrieve the data that you require at any given time. Lots of small calls are better than one large call returning all the data for a customer, for example.

Comment: @DaveRead, it's always better to perform load tests in order to have objective results. Personally I have performed many tests (in applications of mine) in which the conclusion was that network latencies and serialization/deserialization overheads made that it was preferred to make fewer calls with bigger data sets. Of course this will depend.

Answer (score 1):

When you are referring to calls, do you mean WebMethods, or do you mean actual calls to the WebMethod?

I have never heard of a bottleneck in grouping all the webmethods together into one webservice, but one advantage for splitting it out over multiple services would be that you could put each webservice in a different Application pool and that could at least cut down on app pool recycling.

Also, basic Web services have been deprecated in .net 4.0.  They have been replaced with WCF which show some significant performance increases over the old Web Service method.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx for the performance analysis between the two.